# cannot shutdown virtual domain until connected to it

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, shutdown

I have a rather weird problem. I'm going to try and present facts but the truth is that my problem seems so awkward that I don't really know what is happening.

I run a Debian 8.11 host with libvirt-1.2.9.
I have a virtual domain running ok with debian as well.

Fact #1. Starting the domain works fine:

```
virsh start my-domain
```

Fact #2. Stopping the domain FAILS:

```
virsh shutdown my-domain
```

Fact #3. If I SSH into my virtual domain (even just one command), then suddenly stopping the domain works?!?

```
ssh my-domain hostname
virsh shutdown my-domain
```

Do you have an explanation?
How can I programmatically do something to the vm so that it becomes stoppable?
(they don't necessarily all have ssh installed)

Thanks
Santi

Comment: Quote: "I have a virtual domain running ok with debian as well."  
I didn't specify but it's 8.11 as well

Comment: In a way, the guest OS shouldn't matter. What puzzles me is that basically, I cannot use "virsh shutdown" until I have made contact with a guest :
- ssh into linux
- or samba into windows
- or http into macos
It looks like the guest is not receiving any shutdown request until it has served some kind of dedicated request (a request dedicated to its os regardless of the fact it is a vm).

Comment: You have a strange problem, then, and you should be as detailed as possible about the entire environment.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton. I gave what details I thought were necessary. Is there anything else you would like to know or that would give you a better understanding of the problem? Yes it is still there 6 month later.

Comment: You've said almost nothing about the environment except that the host runs Debian 8.11 and libvirt-1.2.9. That's not even a bare minimum of what's necessary. You need to explain what hardware the host is, how it is connected to the Internet, how you set up the virtual networking, and anything else that might possibly be useful even if you don't think it's relevant (because it possibly is).